# Búsqueda de un elemento dentro de un arreglo

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public int busqueda(int arreglo[], int elemento) {
    int centro, primero, ultimo, valorCentro;
    primero = 0;
    ultimo = arreglo.length - 1;
    while (primero <= ultimo){
        centro = (primero + ultimo) / 2;
        valorCentro = arreglo[centro];
        System.out.println(" comparando a " + elemento + " Con " + arreglo[centro]);
        if(elemento==valorCentro){
            return centro;
        } else if (elemento<valorCentro){
            ultimo = centro-1;
        } else {
            primero= centro+1;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}
```

}

[image: Debe imprimirme algo así]Hay un método de búsqueda que necesita que los valores del arreglo estén ordenados, para dividirlo en dos partes y que utiliza recursividad para mejorar el tiempo que se emplea en la tarea. Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar

Comment: Debe imprimr:Ingrese el numero a buscar: 88. ARREGLO  ORDENADO 1 2 7 9 34 42 51 67 88. El 88 se encuentra en la posición: 8

Comment: Coloca el código que llevas al momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es la búsqueda binaria recursiva.

```
public static int busquedaBinariaRecursiva(int[] arreglo, int busqueda, int 
izquierda, int derecha){

    // Si izquierda es mayor que derecha significa que no encontramos nada
    if(izquierda > derecha){
        return -1;
    }

    // Calculamos las mitades...
    int indiceDelElementoDelMedio = (int) Math.floor((izquierda + derecha) / 2);
    int elementoDelMedio = arreglo[indiceDelElementoDelMedio];

    // Ver si está en la mitad
    if(elementoDelMedio == busqueda){
        return indiceDelElementoDelMedio;
    }
    // Si no, entonces vemos si está a la izquierda o derecha

    if(busqueda < elementoDelMedio){
        derecha = indiceDelElementoDelMedio - 1;
        return busquedaBinariaRecursiva(arreglo, busqueda, izquierda, derecha);
    }else{
        izquierda = indiceDelElementoDelMedio + 1;
        return busquedaBinariaRecursiva(arreglo, busqueda, izquierda, derecha);
    }
}
```

Comment: Y para el ingreso del arreglo como seria el codigo???

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Como ingresar datos al arreglo?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar binarySearch de Arrays, ejemplo:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 4, 65, 7, 22, 3 };
    int input = 2;

    int index = search(input, array);

    if (index < 0) {
        System.out.println("No se encontro " + input);
    }

}

public static int search(int input, int[] array) {
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero a Buscar: " + input + "\n");

    System.out.println("ARREGLO ORDENADO \n");

    // Ordernar array
    Arrays.sort(array);

    // Imprimir array Java 8 o mayor | Si usas menor a Java 8 puedes imprimir con
    // for, foreach o iterator
    Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);

    // se obtiene la posicion del valor buscado
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, input);

    // si fue encontrado la posicion sera >= 0
    if (index >= 0) {
        System.out.println("El " + input + " se encuentra en la posición " + index);

        index = input;
    }

    return index;
}
```